# Security server PouchDB

Tags: pouchdb, cloudant

I'm creating a web app (a simple shopping list) using PouchDB and Cloudant.

Every new user will have the possibility to create his own "account" (every user will have a DB in my cloudant account) and every user will save his own shopping list, data, etc.

So, the question is: Is there a way to hide or protect the Cloudant credentials to access the main database with wich every user will interact?

To create a db in pouchDB the syntax is:

```
var remoteDB = ('https://myDB.cloudant.com/myMainDB', {
   auth: {
         username: "myUsername",
         password: "myPassword"
});
```

Since this data is placed inside a .js file every one over the internet can access. Or maybe I'm wrong and PouchDB isn't designed for this purpose.
Thanks to all! :)

Comment: It sounds like you shouldn't be storing usernames and passwords 1) in a public .js file and 2) in clear text. Can't you use something like OAuth for this?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to read in the username and password from environment variables:

```
var username = process.env.COUCH_USER;
var pass = process.env.COUCH_PASS;
```

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: Are you running this completely in the browser? If so, you need to rethink your model. Each user can only be allowed to have access to their own credentials, not the account-level password. You need a separate mechanism for setting up users. Cloudant supports API keys that can be used for this, see https://docs.cloudant.com/authorization.html, and you can also use the CouchDB `_users` database: https://docs.cloudant.com/authorization.html#enabling-the-_users-database-with-cloudant. Or use a mid-layer like Cloudant Envoy (https://github.com/cloudant-labs/envoy)